# Editing a JSON with two arrays. Want to edit at same location in each array

Tags: json

I have a json that looks like:

```
{
  "AlertDestinationAssociations": [
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": null,
      "SecurityName": null
    },
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": "SNMPv3Trap",
      "SecurityName": "oneview_4861333356c624b597366648345"
    },
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": null,
      "SecurityName": null
    },
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": null,
      "SecurityName": null
    },
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": null,
      "SecurityName": null
    },
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": null,
      "SecurityName": null
    },
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": null,
      "SecurityName": null
    },
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": null,
      "SecurityName": null
    }
  ],
  "AlertDestinations": [
    null,
    "1.2.3.4",
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ]
}
```

I want to edit the first null SNMPAlertProtocol and SecurityName.  I then need to edit the corresponding array element in AlertDestinations.  As a first step, I can change all of the null values with:

```
.AlertDestinationAssociations[] | select(.SNMPAlertProtocol == null).SNMPAlertProtocol |= "SNMPv3Trap" | .SecurityName |= "crap"
```

but I have not figured out how to limit that to just the first null element, nor how to edit the corresponding element in the AlertDestinations array.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```bash
jq --argjson pos 0 '
  .AlertDestinationAssociations[$pos] |= {SNMPAlertProtocol: "SNMPv3Trap", SecurityName: "crap"} |
  .AlertDestinations[$pos] |= "10.1.2.3"
' file.json
```

**Output**

```json
{
  "AlertDestinationAssociations": [
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": "SNMPv3Trap",
      "SecurityName": "crap"
    },
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": "SNMPv3Trap",
      "SecurityName": "oneview_4861333356c624b597366648345"
    },
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": null,
      "SecurityName": null
    },
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": null,
      "SecurityName": null
    },
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": null,
      "SecurityName": null
    },
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": null,
      "SecurityName": null
    },
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": null,
      "SecurityName": null
    },
    {
      "SNMPAlertProtocol": null,
      "SecurityName": null
    }
  ],
  "AlertDestinations": [
    "10.1.2.3",
    "1.2.3.4",
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ]
}
```

Comment: This questions is answered.  jpseng gave a great solution.  I'm not sure how to mark it as answered?

Comment: Did not even see those.  :)   done!